# Can I use external map data with cartojs library?

Tags: carto, carto-js, carto-vl

I am receiving data from another source apart from cartodb and I would like to use the data for carto maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing that prevents you to add more layers to your Leaflet or Google Maps map aside from CARTO.js layers, same for Mapbox GL on CARTO VL.

If you are referring to use CARTO.js methods then it only works against a CARTO Maps API server. In the case of VL you can also use GeoJSON or MVT as sources.